# How to free pointer to pointer?

Tags: c, memory, malloc

I am struggling with deallocating my memory in C. The program works fine but the current free statement I have reports a memory leak when running through Dr.Memory. These statements are for a multidimensional array that knows the amount of columns (co) and rows (ro).

```
int **OriginalPixels;
OriginalPixels=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*ro); //utilizing double         pointer
OriginalPixels[0]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*co*ro);// Connects to beginning.
```

I am currently freeing with this statement

```
free(*OriginalPixels);
```

Is this correct? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: `free()` takes input as a pointer. You must first free the memory pointed to by `*OriginalPixels` and then the memory pointed to by `OriginalPixels`.

Comment: If you call `malloc` 100 times, then you need to call `free` 100 times, with the exact same pointer values that `malloc` returned.  Your calls to `free` can be made in any order, but the set of pointers must match or you will have a memory leak (or risk a segmentation fault).  Makes sense, right?

Answer (score 8):

No. Every `malloc` needs a matching `free`. You only have one `free`. but two `malloc`s.

```
 free(OriginalPixels[0]);   
 free(OriginalPixels);
```

Of course, if your array has more than one row, you'll need more of both.

Comment: It looks like his array does have more than one row, but he's allocating them all at once, with `malloc(sizeof(int)*co*ro`.

Comment: @SteveSummit that would be allocating one very long row

Comment: Depends on how he uses it.  Note he's multiplying by `ro`.  I suspect he's allocating something like the `array2` at http://www.c-faq.com/aryptr/dynmuldimary.html .

Answer (score 1):

```
int **OriginalPixels;
OriginalPixels=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)*ro); //utilizing double pointer
OriginalPixels[0]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*co*ro);// Connects to beginning.
```

When you allocate `OriginalPixels` you are allocating `ro` *pointers-to-type-int*. Depending on your system each pointer will be eith `4-bytes` or `8-bytes`. You are allocating space for the *pointer variable* itself, but each pointer currently points nowhere.

When you allocate `OriginalPixels[0]`, you are allocating a block of memory to hold `ro * co` integers. Essentially, you are allocating storage for all `ro` rows of `co` columns. (**note:** all other pointers you allocate are unused and unnecessary)

To free the memory, you must *deallocate* in the *reverse-order* you allocated. Meaning, you must deallocate the block of memory holding the integers, then deallocate the pointers. e.g.

```
free (OriginalPixels[0]);
free (OriginalPixels);
```

**Allocating `ro` Pointers to `co` ints**

**note:** there is little reason to allocate both `OriginalPixels` and `OriginalPixels[0]` in **this** case (i.e. allocating `ro` number of arrays of `co` *ints* and then assigning the starting address for the block to only `OriginalPixels[0]`). If `co` is a constant, you can allocate all at once using an *pointers-to-array-of-*`co`*-int*, e.g.

```
int (*OriginalPixels)[co];
OriginalPixels = malloc (sizeof *OriginalPixels * ro);
```

In this case you can index each integer as you would using the pointer-to-point-to-type, but only need 1 `free`, e.g. `free (OriginalPixels);`

(**note2:**, consider `calloc` when allocating numeric arrays to benefit from the initialization provided)

Here is a short example of allocating the pointer-to-array-of-co-ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { ro = 2, co = 5 };

int main (void) {

    int (*a)[co] = {NULL}, i, j;    /* array a[ro][co]    */
    a = malloc (sizeof *a * ro);    /* validation omitted */

    for (i = 0; i < ro; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < co; j++)
            scanf ("%d", &a[i][j]); /* return chk omitted */

    for (i = 0; i < ro; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < co; j++)
            printf (" %d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    free (a);

    return 0;
}
```

**Memory Error Check**

```
$ echo "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 1" | valgrind ./bin/allocnarray
==11731== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11731== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11731== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11731== Command: ./bin/allocnarray
==11731==
 1 2 3 4 5
 6 7 8 9 1

==11731==
==11731== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11731==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11731==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 40 bytes allocated
==11731==
==11731== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11731==
==11731== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11731== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
```

Comment: *an array-of-pointers-to-co-int,* This is not correct, however you use the phrase correctly later. This: `int (*a)[co] = {NULL},` is misleading as `a` is a pointer and not an array it should be `int (*a)[co] = NULL`. Also consider avoiding declaring multiple variables on the same line: `int (*a)[co] = {NULL}, i, j;`. It reduces readability, at no benefit.

Comment: The intent was *pointer-to-array-of-co-int*, the reversal of the terms seems to be due to early-onset senility. Fixed.